# How to update review request in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

Our team is using phabricator to review code. In eclipse, we can post a review request by added `Auditors: someone` in comment when check in repository. Is there a command patch in comment to update the review request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arc uses information about the working copy (like the path, branch name, local commit hashes, and local tree hashes, depending on which version control system you are using) to figure out whether you intend to create or update a revision. If it guesses incorrectly, you can force it to either create or update a revision with:

`$ arc diff --update <revision>`

see http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Arcanist_User_Guide_arc_diff.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arcanist`, command `arc diff` and `arc update`